# Limit of non bijective operators is not bijective?

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume you have a sequence $(A_n)$ of non bijective operators where $A_n \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$) on some Banach space $X$.

Assume $A_n$ is convergent with respect to the strong operator topology e.g.

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_nx$ exists for all $x\in X$.

By $A:=s$-$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$ we denote the corresponding limit of $A_n$ in the strong operator topology.

Is $A$ also non invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the space $X=\ell^2$ and put $A_n(x_1,x_2,\dots):=(x_1,\dots,x_n,0,0,0,\dots)$. Then $A_n$ is non-invertible (it is non-bijective), but $A_n\to\text{Id}_X$ in the strong operator topology.

If the convergence was in norm, then the answer would be yes, since the set of invertible operators is open in $L(X)$ with respect to the norm topology.